# Why does xdg-open use wslview?

Tags: kubuntu, wine, kde, kde5, xdg-open

Using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, KDE Plasma 5, with wine 7.8 installed.

When I try to use the command `xdg-open .` the expected mime type (for inode/directory is Dolphin) is not invoked.  Instead `wslview` is invoked.  Furthermore I receive an error trying to open the windows registry console tool, but fails to find the file:

### Original Error:

```
barry@barry-laptop:~$ xdg-open .
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
WSL Interopability is disabled. Please enable it before using WSL.
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
[error] WSL Interoperability is disabled. Please enable it before using WSL.
/usr/bin/wslview: line 216: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/reg.exe: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/wslview: line 308: [: -ge: unary operator expected
[error] This protocol is not supported before version 1903.
```

I would like to control `xdg-open` using mime types, not wslview.

### Mime Type for inode/directory:

```
barry@barry-laptop:~$ xdg-mime query filetype .
inode/directory
barry@barry-laptop:~$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
org.kde.dolphin.desktop
```

Why is it using wslview and not the registered mime types?

### Research:

by issuing the command `sh -x /usr/bin/xdg-open .` I see `xdg-open .` gets translated into `kde-open5 .`

```
barry@barry-laptop:~$ sh -x /usr/bin/xdg-open .
+ check_common_commands .
+ [ 1 -gt 0 ]
+ parm=.
+ shift
+ [ 0 -gt 0 ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ unset XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL
+ [ 0 -lt 1 ]
+ xdg_redirect_output= > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
+ [ x. != x ]
+ url=
+ [ 1 -gt 0 ]
+ parm=.
+ shift
+ [ -n  ]
+ url=.
+ [ 0 -gt 0 ]
+ [ -z . ]
+ detectDE
+ unset GREP_OPTIONS
+ [ -n KDE ]
+ DE=kde
+ [ xkde = x ]
+ [ xkde = x ]
+ [ xkde = x ]
+ [ xkde = xgnome ]
+ [ -f /run/user/1000/flatpak-info ]
+ [ xkde = x ]
+ DEBUG 2 Selected DE kde
+ [ -z  ]
+ return 0
+ open_kde .
+ [ -n 5 ]
+ kde-open5 .
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
WSL Interopability is disabled. Please enable it before using WSL.
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
[error] WSL Interoperability is disabled. Please enable it before using WSL.
+ [ 0 -eq 0 ]
+ exit_success
+ [ 0 -gt 0 ]
+ exit 0
```

`kde-open5` is a symbolic link to `kde-open`

```
barry@barry-laptop:~$ which kde-open5
/usr/bin/kde-open5
barry@barry-laptop:~$ ls -alh /usr/bin/kde-open5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 May  5 12:56 /usr/bin/kde-open5 -> kde-open
barry@barry-laptop:~$ which kde-open
/usr/bin/kde-open
barry@barry-laptop:~$ ls -alh /usr/bin/kde-open
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39K Mar 30 02:19 /usr/bin/kde-open
```

`kde-open` is binary file and not viewable via VIM.  Unclear how to configure the relationships between the file type and the application since it does not honor mime types.

Comment: `wslview` is part of the package `wslu` (WSL utilities) and it is installed by default in Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL. Did you install `wslu` manually? --- The main use of `wslview` it to open the Window's default web browser (and other default applications) from within WSL. This tool is normally not needed on systems not running in WSL.

Comment: I don't recall installing it. Perhaps it was a dependency from another package that was installed...

Comment: To check the files `kde-open5` operates with (to find the configuration files / symlinks) you can use `strace` which will show you the executed syscalls: `strace -fe %file kde-open5 .` Be prepared that you will probably see a lot of syscalls (libraries, locale files etc.)

Comment: Thanks pabouk - I will check it out...

Comment: See this bug for an explanation:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemsettings/+bug/1978842

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I looked into it. I've found that `wslview` declares that it handles the `x-scheme-handler/file` mimetype in its desktop entry located at `/usr/share/wslu/wslview.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WSLView
Comment=Open files and addresses in Windows
Icon=windows
Exec=/usr/bin/wslview %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/file
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26
```

I guess the scheme handler for `file://` takes precendence over the file's mimetype when `xdg-open` decides how to open a file; so every file is opened using `wslview`. Uninstalling it fixed my issue.